# installing basemap/geos in mac by source code

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I know there is some posts about the installation of basemap, but after I follow every step from the instruction here, it still not work for me.
https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

When I run *python setup.py install*, it keeps complaining "geos_c.h" file not found. How do I know I have installed geos correctly? When I *make*, there are a lot of output but no way to know if it install successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

problems solved guys!

Instead of installing the geos from the package in the basemap, I use brew to install it (and proj), then python setup.py install to install basemap again, it work!